# Ошибка зацикливания. python

Tags: python, циклы, for

Цикл работает не так как мне нужно.
Вот код:

```
import os
import re

os.chdir('E:\\test')
open_file_read = open('test.txt', 'r')

lines_total = ''
for lines in open_file_read.readlines():
    lines_total += lines

compile_name = re.compile(r'[а-я А-Я \.]+')

compile_3 = re.compile(r'[0-9]+')
print(compile_3.findall(lines_total))

names_ball = {}

for elements in compile_name.findall(lines_total):
    for elements2 in compile_3.findall(lines_total):
        names_ball[elements] = elements2

print(names_ball)

keys_total = ''
for keys in names_ball.keys():
    keys_total += keys

values_total = ''
for values in names_ball.values():
    values_total += values

if int(values_total) < 3:
    print(keys_total)
else:
    pass
```

Содержимое файла test.txt:

```
Иванов О. 4
Петров И. 3
Дмитриев Н. 2
Смирнова О. 4
Керченских В. 5
Котов Д. 2
Бирюкова Н. 1
Данилов П. 3
Аранских В. 5
Лемонов Ю. 2
Олегова К. 4
```

Вывод программы:

```
['4', '3', '2', '4', '5', '2', '1', '3', '5', '2', '4']

{'Иванов О. ': '4', 'Петров И. ': '4', 'Дмитриев Н. ': '4', 'Смирнова О. ': '4', 'Керченских В. ': '4', 'Котов Д. ': '4', 'Бирюкова Н. ': '4', 'Данилов П. ': '4', 'Аранских В. ': '4', 'Лемонов Ю. ': '4', 'Олегова К. ': '4'}
```

Вывод должен быть:

```
{'Иванов О. ': '4', 'Петров И. ': '3', 'Дмитриев Н. ': '2', 'Смирнова О. ': '4', 'Керченских В. ': '5', 'Котов Д. ': '2', 'Бирюкова Н. ': '1', 'Данилов П. ': '3', 'Аранских В. ': '5', 'Лемонов Ю. ': '2', 'Олегова К. ': '4'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно тут перебираете найденные элементы, в результате присваиваете каждому элементу словаря по очереди все числа и в итоге там остаётся только самое последнее число:

```
for elements in compile_name.findall(lines_total):
    for elements2 in compile_3.findall(lines_total):
        names_ball[elements] = elements2
```

Параллельно две последовательности надо перебирать так:

```
for elements,elements2 in zip(compile_name.findall(lines_total), compile_3.findall(lines_total):
    names_ball[elements] = elements2
```

Хотя я бы вообще тут всё по-другому сделал, но проще всего исправить в данном случае так.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь)